# iOS: Stream audio file with pause, forward functions

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, stream

I know how to stream an audio file to iphone. But does anyone know how to include functions like pause, or having a slider bar to fast forward to downloaded portions of the audio?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the `AudioSteamer` classes in [this project](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) by Matt Gallagher with a lot of success. It was simple enough to implement my own progress slider using a `NSTimer` to poll the current duration, and the classes implement a `seekToTime:` function to allow moving the slider to change the position in the stream.

Comment: Thanks! I personally due to lack of time/expertise, i just used the webview to stream the audio file. =)